# How can I switch to a different browser during a Cucumber Capybara test?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

I am currently using Thor to set an environment before running tests, this will lock me into firefox or chrome. My objective is to switch to a different browser during the test and continue there. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: When you say "switch to a different browser during the test" do you mean to use 2 different browsers during a single scenario, or do you mean to use different browsers for separate scenarios?

Comment: What you would achieve by executing few steps in one browser and then executing few in another browser. Also are scenarios not dependent on other ?